# tinyMCE plugin with Ember

Tags: ember.js, tinymce

I am writing my own tinyMCE plug-in which needs to access some Ember context, such as a service.

It seems that tinyMCE loads its plugins at load time, before I have a chance to intervene or override anything.

Is there any more elegant alternative than exporting the Ember application global and accessing it from within the plugin?

Is it feasible to avoid tinyMCE's plugin loading architecture altogether and add my own call to `tinymce.PluginManager.add` from within Ember code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by writing an Ember service which calls `tinymce.PluginManager.add` at initialization time.